# React: Is it bad practice to import a child component directly rather than pass in as a dependency?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-redux, enzyme

I may be over thinking this, but I am curious if importing a child component directly is bad practice with regards to coupling and testing.

Below is a simple example:

```js
import Header from './header.jsx';

class Widget extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header></Header>
                <div>{this.props.importantContent}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

To me it looks like there is now coupling between `Widget` and `Header`. With regards to testing, I don't see an easy way to mock the `Header` component when testing the `Widget` component.

How do other larger React apps handle cases like this? Should I pass `Header` in as a prop? If using `react-redux`, I can inject header with the `Connect` method like below to reduce boilerplate. Is that sound?

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './header.jsx';

class Widget extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.header}
                <div>{this.props.importantContent}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    header: Header
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Widget)
```

I am interested is simple doing what the community is generally doing. I see that one solution is doing shallow rendering to test on the main part of the component and not the child components using something like [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme).

Thoughts or other ideas?

Comment: I do not think "it is bad". It is surely not best practices since it decrease the readability of the code and thus make it harder to maintain. In both cases you keep the dependency for widget to have a header component. I don't know about other large app, but I've never seen someone using it this way.

Comment: Good thoughts, but I think maybe a little bit off the mark. In both situations you still have a `Header` dependancy. The second example is also more boilerplate, not less. Unless your component needs to be able to display different headers, there is no benefit to passing it as a prop that I can think of.

Comment: Your second codeblock example is strange. If you want to pass components through a prop then do just that. Then wherever in your code you're actually using your widget, that's where you pass Header `<Widget header={Header} />` you can always use a default Header if one isn't provided

Answer (score 1):

Passing elements / components as props is a good idea. Having default props is a good idea too:

```
const Widget = ({
  header = <div>Default Header.. </div>,
  content = <div>Default Content.. </div> 
}) =>
  <div>
    {header}
    {content}
  </div>
```

Then elsewhere in your app:

```
<Widget header={<Header title="Foo" />} content="content from props" />
```

No need to inject using `connect`

You can also pass a component, not just an element if you want to interact with props / send data back to parent:

```
const Widget = ({
  Header = props => <div>Default Header.. </div>,
  Content = props => <div>Default Content.. </div> 
}) =>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Content />
  </div>
```

Elsewhere:

```
<Widget Header={Header} Content={props => <Content />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the component always renders the same thing it can be directly rendered as a child rather than the parent.

If all other portions of the Component remain constant and only the Header can be different across pages then you could actually implement it as an HOC instead of passing it as a props

```
const MyCompFactory = ({CustomHeader = DefaultHeader}) => {
  return class Widget extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <CustomHeader/>
                    <div>{this.props.importantContent}</div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

}
```

and use it like

```
const CustomComponent = MyCompFactory({CustomComponent: Header})
```

as long as testing is concerned in your case, you could just shallow render your component and then Search if the Header component is rendered something like

```
import Header from 'path/to/header'

const component = shallow(
    <Widget {...customProps}/>
)

test('test' , () => {
   expect(component.find(Header).exists()).toBe(true)
})
```